# Merging two commands in one

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a requirement where I need to combine below commands. Basically merging the first command in 2nd command.

```
head -2 $in_folder_nm"/"$in_hash_file| tail -1 > format.txt
as_of_dt=`date -f <(cut -c1-10 format.txt ) +'%Y%m%d'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replacing `head`, `tail` and `cut` with `sed`, you could do as following:

```
date -d"$(sed -n '2{s/^\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/p;q}' -- "$path/$tofile")" +'%Y%m%d'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just pipe the output of your `tail -1` into your `cut -c1-10`. Then everything is in one line.

Also, it's not clear why you use `date -f <(...)` instead of just `date "$(...)"`.